# Proof of gaussian process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I want to show that the limit of:
$$X_n(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(t)Y_i$$
namely $$X_\infty(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(t)Y_i$$
is a Gaussian process, where $f_i(t)$ is a deterministic function and $Y_i$ is a i.i.d. sequence of standard normal.

I'm reading the following proof that show that $c^TX$ is normally distributed for any $c\in\mathbb R^n$.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}c_iX_{t_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}c_i\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f_j(t)Y_j=lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_j\sum_{i=1}^{m}c_if_j(t)=lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jY_j$$

and it conclude saying that $lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jY_j$ is a linear combination of independent $N(0,1)$ and therefore it is normal and the limit too.

What do you think about the following proof and there is some other alternative? What i don't understand is for example how is made the vector X and why if in the first equality on the lhs we have $X_{t_i}$ then in the rhs it only depend on $j$ and no more on $i$. Moreover also the last eqaulity it is not clear to me. any help?

Comment: The definition of $X_n$ does not make sense. There is no $n$ on the right side.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry you are right, I edited it

Answer (score 0):

The argument is basically right but you have to change $t$ to $t_i$ in the inside sum $ \sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} f_j(t)Y_j$.

Comment: everything else it is right? why can't i note that $(f_1Y_1,..,f_nY_n)$ is multivariate normal and then i know that the linear map $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f_i(t)Y_i$ is normal too?

Comment: Since the definition of $X_n$ involves an infinite sum you have to use two facts: 1) linear combinations of jointly normal variables are normal, 2) limits of normal variables are normal. @Alias__

Comment: okey, then following the same approach i could say that $(f_1Y_1,..,f_nY_n)$ is multivariate normal and then i know that the linear map $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(t)Y_i$ is normal too, finally taking the limit for $n \to \infty$ is normal too. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: So it is always true that if $(Y_1,..,Y_n)$ is multivariate gaussian then also $(f_1Y_1,..,f_nY_n)$ is multivariate gaussian?

Comment: @Alias__ Yes, that is true.